# Breadcrumb in sharepoint

Tags: 2010

I would like to have breadcrumb that does not display document library name in breadcrumb trail.For example if i use SPContentMapProvider it will create breadcrumb like Home-->Subsite--> docLib-->DocsetTitle so in order to remove docLib i have tried another sitemapProvider called CurrentNavSiteMapProviderNoEncode which remove docLib but dont see docsetTitle either.
i would like to see Home-->subsite--->DocsetTitle.

Please advise

Thanks 
ROnak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks i have used this link as starting point of creating custom control for breadcrumb and its working fine.

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/building-breadcrumbs-sharepoint-2010/

Thanks waldek for great information on your blog.

ROnak

Answer (score 0):

You could just do the following in the masterpage or on the page where you would *not* want to show the document library from the breadcrumb:

```
[script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"]
var breadCrumbs = document.getElementById
('ctl00_PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb_ContentMap')
if (breadCrumbs != null)
{
    if (breadCrumbs.childNodes.length >= 3)
    {
        if (breadCrumbs.childNodes[2].innerHTML.indexOf('Pages') > 0)
        {
            breadCrumbs.childNodes[1].innerHTML = "";
            breadCrumbs.childNodes[2].innerHTML = "";
        }
    }
}
[/script]
//Change '"[","]" to "<",">" in script tag.
```

This was taken from here: http://kadyanmossnuts.blogspot.co.uk/2008/08/hide-document-library-name-like-pages.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply  i can not hardcode pages or some doclib name.i am looking for c# solution.